# Certain block matrix

Tags: matrix, tensors

A block matrix like
$$m_{(ij),(kl)}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$$
can be constructed as

```
L=3;
id=IdentityMatrix[L];
m=KroneckerProduct[id, id];
```

But how to construct
$$m_{(ij),(kl)}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}(1-\delta_{ij})$$
without explicitly using `Table`? With table is can be constructed as

```
t=Table[KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] (1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j]), {i, L}, {j, L}, {k, L}, {l, L}];
m = Flatten[Tph, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}];
```

Comment: Can you show what it should look like? Use `Table` once?

Comment: `m1=Array[KroneckerDelta[#1,#2]KroneckerDelta[#3,#4](1-KroneckerDelta[#1,#3])&,{L,L,L,L}]//ArrayFlatten` and `m2=TensorProduct[id, id]TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[1 - id, Array[1 &, {L, L}]], {1, 3, 2, 4}]//ArrayFlatten`, then `m1===m2` returns `True`

Comment: @MikeY see my edit

Comment: @lilyric Why don't you answer, just comment?

Comment: Acturally I don't know what do you mean by "without explicitly using Table". `Array` can be regarded as an anonymous version of `Table`, or using `Tensor*` functions re-write your expression, or construct it directly like the answer of @user293787.

Comment: @lilyric Indeed, both suggestions are quite similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use

```
DiagonalMatrix[1-Flatten[IdentityMatrix[L]]]
```